# Is it possible to synchronize with Microsoft Sync Framework through FTP-transfers?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I'm looking at synchronize methods between two databases and found Microsoft Sync Framework recently.
I've been trying to investigate if it suits my needs.

My scenario is the following:

Two SQL-databases located in different geographical parts. The remote database can go without internet connection for days at times and for some locations the only means of communicating is with ftp transfers to the main server.

So my question is: 
Is it possible to sync between two servers and send the sync-information and data through a ftp-server?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's definitely possible for SQL synchronisations, but with file synchronisation scenarios you can do this by writing your own sync providers. See: [Creating Synchronization Providers With The Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872391.aspx)

I would think something similar is possible.